# How do I make a helper method available to factories? (Rails, Rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am attempting to invoke a helper method inside of a factory, but it consistently comes back as method not found. Here is the helper method

/spec/helpers/factories.rb

```
module Helpers
  module Factories

    def array_of_fakers(faker_class, field, number_of_elements)
      faker_array = Array.new
      number_of_elements.times do
        factory_array.push(class_eval(faker_class).send(field))
      end
      faker_array
    end

  end
end
```

it is called like this...

```
factory :salesman do
    clients { Helpers::Factories.array_of_fakers("Faker::Company", "name", rand(1..5)) }
    ...
end
```

I have tried requiring in rails_helper, spec_helper and the file itself, but all return the same results. I have also tried it without including the module names and just the method name, but that doesn't work either. Is this possible?

Comment: Make it module-level: `def array_of_fakers ...` → `def self.array_of_fakers ...`.

Comment: Thanks Aleksei. Just that change alone hasn't made a difference. Should I be referencing it with the module names included like I do above? Where should I be including and/or requiring the helper?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but... Is this really worth making a helper method for?? I'd just write: `clients {  rand(1..5).times.map { Faker::Company.name } }`

Comment: @Carl it must work; you are calling it right, just make sure the helper is loaded (e.g. autoloaded in rails.)

Comment: @TomLord That does make sense to do it that way. I would still like to know how to get a helper method working, though, as nothing I do seems to get it working.

Comment: Are you getting a method missing error or a constant missing error?

Comment: It's a method missing error @max

Comment: If you added `def self.array_of_fakers` as suggested by @AlekseiMatiushkin then it does not make sense and I would chalk it up to user error. Make sure you actually saved the file etc.

Comment: I don't think I am including the file correctly. Right now I have at the top of factory, "require 'spec/helpers/factories'. Is there somwhere else I should have it or should the syntax be any different?

Comment: If the file was not loaded you would get a missing constant error. I'm 99% sure its some kind of slop error. Try going through the steps of creating a minimal example and you'll most likely eliminate it in the process.

Answer (score 7):

Check out the ***spec/support/factory_bot.rb*** config file setup recommended in the factory_bot [GETTING_STARTED.md](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) doc...

In my case, I was not using rails, but this worked for me:

```
# spec/support/factory_bot.rb
    
# frozen_string_literal: true
    
require 'factory_bot'

# Add this...
#
# Require the file(s) with your helper methods. In my case, the
# helper methods were under Support::FileHelpers.
require_relative 'file_helpers'
    
# This is just the standard setup recommended for inclusion in a non-rails app.
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
    
  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryBot.find_definitions
  end
end

# ...and this...
# Include your helpers.
FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner.send(:include, Support::FileHelpers)
```

Comment: With my Rails app, I only needed to put the last line into the file!

Answer (score 0):

Include your helper module in `FactoryBot::DefinitionProxy`:

```rb
# spec/helpers/factories.rb

module Helpers
  module Factories

    def array_of_fakers(faker_class, field, number_of_elements)
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# spec/support/factory_bot_extension.rb
# (or any other file that gets required in spec/spec_helper.rb)

require_relative './helpers/factories'

FactoryBot::DefinitionProxy.send(:include, Helpers::Factories)
```

```rb
# spec/factories/salesman.rb

factory :salesman do
  clients { array_of_fakers("Faker::Company", "name", rand(1..5)) }
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `spec/factories` folder

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  sequence(:id) { SecureRandom.uuid }
  sequence(:email) { Faker::Internet.unique.safe_email }
  sequence(:name) { Faker::Name.name }
end
```

And then just call it in your factories like this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_factory do
    uuid { generate(:id) }
    name { generate(:name) } 
    email { generate(:email) } 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
module Helpers
  module Factories
    module_function

    def array_of_fakers(faker_class, field, number_of_elements)
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

or:

```rb
module Helpers
  module Factories
    def self.array_of_fakers(faker_class, field, number_of_elements)
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

The former is prettier IMO, but either should work.  In a result, you can call `::Helpers::Factories.array_of_fakers` from anywhere.  Note the leading double colon which may be needed sometimes.